# Trouble parsing string date in us with the Datetime.TryParse

Tags: c#, date, cultureinfo

I'm trying to put a variable, stored in a string format in a dateTime variable.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo usaDateFormatInfo = culture.DateTimeFormat;

string sDataStored = "10/15/2011";
if (DateTime.TryParse(sDataStored , usaDateFormatInfo,       System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out TestedDateTime))
DateTime dMyUSDateTime = TestedDateTime;
```

Unfortunately, the final result in my variable is not : "10/15/2011" but "15/10/2011" (the french culture, which is the current culture of the application for the moment).

Same result with the TryParseExact.

I could go thru a "Convert", inside a "try/catch", but Im sure there are other better way to solve this problem... 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, the final result is "10/15/2011" instead of "10/15/2011"? Errrrr... They're the same...

Comment: Ok you got It... I made a small mistake :) corrected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say the result is `15/11/2011` where are you seeing that? In the debugger? The debugger will just format the variable according to your current culture (by just calling ToString).

**The DateTime object doesn't stored the culture** it was parsed from. You need to pass the culture to it when you convert it back to a string so it formats according to the US culture.

e.g.

```
dMyUsDateTime.ToString(usaDateFormatInfo)
```

Comment: The "out DateTime" ? How do I pass the culture to the out DateTime object ?

Comment: @PetersLast what are you doing with the DateTime? you need to pass the culture to it when you convert it back to a sting.

Comment: The 15/11/2011 appears in the DateTime value dMyUSDateTime  and TestedDateTime. It is finally displayed on my web application in a Teleriks calendar control textbox.

Comment: @PetersLast Ok, so your real question is, How do I format a DateTime to a different culture in Telerik's Calendar Control? Try asking a new question to that effect.

Comment: the fact is I want to get my result in a DateTime, not in a string :)

Comment: well, no, I dont think Telerik is the problem : my DateTime value is not correct. (trhu my spy editor)

Comment: @PeterLast Your result is a DateTime. It is correctly representing the date you parsed. If you inspect it you will see the year, month, day all match. The format of the DateTime is a different matter.

Comment: @PetersLast the spy editor is also formatting the date time to your current culture.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to have a test transforming my current culture from "fr-FR" to "en-US". Ill give a return fastly. (thx)

Comment: @PetersLast Have a look at this: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar-culture-info.html

Comment: My calendar is correctly setted to US ;) but I did not understood why, the result of my DateTime value was in FR culture, not in US.

Comment: @PetersLast, one last time. The DateTime structure is independent of culture. January 1st 2011 is the same in date in all cultures. The only difference is in how it's displayed, that's when the cultures come in to play. Whatever applications you are using to view the DateTime structure are applying the culture. Visual Studio's Debug View generally just calls ToString() to display the value of a variable which will also apply the default culture.

Comment: I confirm, transforming the web.config cultureinfo, resolve the problem. Strange.

Answer (score 3):

A DateTime doesn't have a culture attached to it. When you want to display a DateTime value, you need to specify the date/time format to use. If you don't specify a format (or view the value in the Visual Studio debugger), the current thread's current culture is used.

```
string result = someDateTime.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
// result == "10/15/2011"
```

Comment: I already got the string, thats the variable DateTime (in the correct format) I would like to get. Actually, transform string sDate "10/15/2011" in DateTime dResult.ToShortDateString = "10/15/2011" and not "15/10/2011" as it is currently.